# Why is dash the new default shell among Debian squeeze

Tags: shell, debian-squeeze

Can anybody tell me why Debian changed the default shell from bash to dash?

I run in different issues with the new shell and I would like to understand what's the cause for this change.

Comment: Your question shows a [lack of research](https://www.google.com/search?q=why+is+dash+the+debian+default+shell).  The first few links of that search explain why the change was made, [particularly this one](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh).  [Changing it back is easy](http://wiki.debian.org/DashAsBinSh).  Sticking to the POSIX standard will help you avoid incompatibility problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Debian website](http://packages.debian.org/nl/squeeze/dash):

The Debian Almquist Shell (dash) is a POSIX-compliant shell derived from ash.

Since it executes scripts faster than bash, and has fewer library dependencies (making it more robust against software or hardware failures), it is used as the default system shell on Debian systems.